# Using input tag helper "name" and getting input value empty. ASP.NET MVC (.NET 5)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have simple form for creating items

```
    <form asp-action="CreateItem" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" name="Photo" class="form-control-file" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.ItemType" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var itemType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RandApp.Enums.ItemType)))
                    {
                        <option value="@itemType.ToString()">@itemType</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var materialType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RandApp.Enums.MaterialType)))
                    {
                        <option value="@materialType.ToString()">@materialType</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.MaterialType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Color" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.Color" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var color in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RandApp.Enums.ItemColor)))
                    {
                        <option value="@color.ToString()">@color</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Color" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Size" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.Size" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var size in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RandApp.Enums.ItemSize)))
                    {
                        <option value="@size.ToString()">@size</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Size" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var desigendFor in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RandApp.Enums.DesignedFor)))
                    {
                        <option value="@desigendFor.ToString()">@desigendFor</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.DesignedFor" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="@Model.Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

there is its controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateItem(Item item, IFormFile Photo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "assets", Photo.FileName);
                var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                await Photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
                item.ItemPhoto = Photo.FileName;
                await _itemRepo.CreateAsync(item);
                ViewBag.Item = item;
                return RedirectToAction("ReadItems");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

my goal is to get the path of chosen photo and save it in folder called "assets"(located in "wwwroot" folder).
The problem is that when i fill the fields and submitting the values, i get item.ItemPhoto value null and i can't enter in if statement. (see the photo down below).
**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2aLt.png**

one solution i have found is to remove "enctype="multipart/form-data" from form and "name="Photo" tag helper from input

```
<form asp-action="CreateItem" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" name="Photo" class="form-control-file" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

but in this case i can't get the path properly.
what can i do to solve this problem, why am i getting empty value from input?

Comment: The path on the client is not valid on the server -- in fact, the browser won't send that over. What are you trying to accomplish by passing the client-side file location? The `IFormFile` has the `FileName` property.

Comment: i want to get the photo, upload it to cloudinary and then generate it as card at the main page. i read that there is no way to get the full path of file due to browser privacy but i found this solution but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File and string type cannot be passed together with the same name **automatically** and cannot achieve this requirement by using just one input. You can set a hidden input for `ItemPhoto` and use js to set the value when the file changed:

```
@model Item
<form asp-action="CreateItem" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="control-label"></label>
                                    //change here...
                <input type="file" name="ItemPhoto" class="form-control-file" onchange="SetValue(this)"  />
                             //add hidden input......
                <input asp-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" hidden/>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ItemPhoto" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function SetValue(input) {
            var fileName = input.files[0].name;
            //asp-for will generate the id and name
            //so you can get the selector by using $("#ItemPhoto")
            $("#ItemPhoto").val(fileName);          
        }
    </script>
}
```

Backend (***The name attribute should always match with the parameter/property name***):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateItem(Item item, IFormFile ItemPhoto)
{
    //....
    return View();
}
```

Comment: sorry for being late. I am little unfamiliar with js so i am kind of confused. could please explain in details what this code will do, i mean do i get full path of file(e.g image) and then show it as an image? my goal is to create items from admin page and then render them on user page but i can't render images at all

Comment: Your requirement is to post both ItemPhoto and file to backend. But they are different type so that they cannot be received in backend with the same name. The js is used to set the ItemPhoto value with the file name when you choose the file. For render the image is a new issue now. If you want to render the image, you need be sure get the correct path for the image corresponding property.

Comment: In the beginning, i was planning to upload these images to cloudinary and then get them from there, but the problem was the same, i couldnt get the full path. So my main question is that with the code that you provided, will i be able to get the full path of the file?

Comment: Hi @SabaMinashvili, of course you can. Let me tell you the whole process to help you easy understanding. You choose the file from local and use js to get the file name and set the file name for `ItemPhoto`. Then submit form to your backend to get the IFormFile and the ItemPhoto. For this line `var path = Path.Combine(xx,xx,xx)`, will get your path. Then if you want to render the image by `asp-for="ItemPhoto"`, you need reset it with value `item.ItemPhoto="/assets/"+item.ItemPhoto`.

Comment: ooohh now i got it :) thank you very much, you have no idea how long i have been stack on this problem.

Comment: Glad to help you.